# Using AS7 with Spring and Log4J, Why cant I get spring trace out to console

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jboss, log4j, jboss7.x

Using AS7 with Spring and Log4J, Why cant I get spring trace out to console.

Here is my log4f.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
    <log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
        <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
            <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n" />
            </layout>
        </appender>


        <appender name="dailyrollinglogfile" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
            <param name="file" value="./inquiry.log" />
            <param name="immediateFlush" value="true" />
            <param name="append" value="true" />
            <param name="datePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
            <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n" />
            </layout>
        </appender>

        <root>
            <priority value="trace"/>
            <appender-ref ref="console"/>
        </root>


    </log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: the appender you showed is dailyrollinglogfile, not console, probably the console appender has a priority (level) filter on it

Comment: sorry I had to fix the foratting of this question

Comment: Did you remove `commons-logging` from the classpath?

Comment: exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>

Comment: Under which spring dependency?

Comment: yes.. 

dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

Comment: What version of JBoss AS 7? You might need to exclude the servers log4j library.